# how to find specific XML data by attribute name/value in flash AS2?

Tags: flash, xml-parsing, actionscript-2

Given the following XML code:

```
 <set name="thumbsBooks">
     <set name="pdf">
         <thumb>Data I want to access</thumb>
         <thumb>Data I want to access</thumb>
     </set>
     <set name="printed">
         <thumb>Data I don't want to access</thumb>
         <thumb>Data I don't want to access</thumb>
     </set>
 <set>
```

I want to be able to get the data contained in the "thumb" tags using the "name" attribute value of the parent tag as a selector, something like you would do in jQuery: $('set[name="pdf"]').find('thumb');

Is there a method like this in Action Script 2 (can't use AS3)?

Answer (score 0):

Just realized that I've changed your parent tag to sets.

```
var myXML:XML = new XML(
<sets name="thumbsBooks">
     <set name="pdf">
         <thumb>Data I want to access</thumb>
         <thumb>Data I want to access</thumb>
     </set>
     <set name="printed">
         <thumb>Data I don't want to access</thumb>
         <thumb>Data I don't want to access</thumb>
     </set>
 </sets>);



for each ( var mySet:XML in myXML.set ) {

      if( mySet.@name == "pdf" ) {
         // do your stuff
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

AS2 used to have an XPath implementation, even two iirc. Both of them sucked beyond any conceivable reason, so I'm not really advising you to use them, yet it would solve this and similar problems very simply.

http://osflash.org/xpath4as2 here's something I could find. There was also something in mx.* package, but it's of a disastrous quality...

If you are limited to the player version rather than particular language version, I'd advise you to take a look at Haxe. It has some nice[er] API for working with XML, then regular DOM API that you have in AS2.

I used to have an XML-wrapper class to reduce the verbosity of XML-related operations, but I didn't touch AS2 in so many years, I think that class is irreversibly lost now... However, if your example happens to be the real life example - why not just use DOM? It doesn't seem that much work to me, unless you really have an overload of XML processing in your project...